# How to avoid border breaks in the table?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, tabularx, ltablex, border

I have a table, and in some pages I have border breaks, how to fix that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}  % Включаем пакет для поддержки русского
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in, hmargin=2cm, top=4cm, bottom=4cm, headheight=3cm, footskip=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|>{\hspace{0pt}}p{2.2cm}|l|>{\hspace{0pt}}p{2cm}|X|l|}\hline
№& Описание отклонения & Департамент & Идентифицированный риск & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Не 
идентифицированный риск 1} \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline  
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline  
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline  
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & 
Объект 1 \\\hline
1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного риска & 
НИ Риск  \\\cline{5-6}
&           &           &           & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск &  Объект 1 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I prefer:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|>{\hspace{0pt}}p{2.2cm}|l|>{\hspace{0pt}}p{2cm}|X|l|}\hline
    №& Описание отклонения & Департамент & Идентифицированный риск & 
    \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Не идентифицированный риск 1} \\\hline
\endhead
        1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного
```

then you'll get at every new page the header. You can force a pagebreak with

```
[...]
   &    &    &    & Объект / процесс, в которос появился этот риск & Объект 1 \\\hline
\pagebreak
   1   & ОТКЛОНЕНИЕ 1   & Департамент 1  & Риск 1  & Описание не идентифицированного 
[...]
```